# Google My Business Information API - Get locations list of the authenticated account with php library

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I'm currently working with Google API through [this](https://github.com/spotonlive/php-google-my-business) great php library but it doesn't support the last API and most of his method [are going to be deprecated](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates).

I already developed the Google authentication.

I now need to get the list of the locations managed by the authenticated Google account.

I'm quite sure I need to call [this api](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list) but I need to do it through the [official PHP library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client).

Unfortunately there isn't any documentation of this PHP library so I tried different approach but I was never able to get them.

Here one of my attempt:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($this->CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->addScope(self::GOOGLE_CLIENT_SCOPE);
$client->setAccessToken($this->gmb_access_token);
$this->gmb_client = new Google\Service\MyBusinessBusinessInformation($client);
$account_locations = $this->gmb_client->accounts_locations->getLocations;
```

But the response is empty.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If this can help, I was missing to request Google to white list my App, that you need to do on this online form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XTQc-QEjsE7YrgstyJxbFDnwmhUhBFFvpNJBw3VzuuE/viewform
Another important thing: you can only have one white listed App for business!